# Not able to create table in database while using back4app( which is based on parse framework)

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, backend, back4app

I performed whole task as given in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhA-XSdy9kA 
but then also no any table got created in dashboard please suggest if any step missing in this video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in solving the issue. In video it wasn't shown to give user permissions.